# Complex deduplication in PostgreSQL using multiple conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I have data on the performance of students MOOCs in a PostgreSQL database. I am trying to munge the data so that I can use it in a marketing funnel-type analysis. The idea is to look the transitions among these stages: how many students sign up, how many open the course, how many take more than half the quizzes, and how many get >90% on all their quizzes.

The problem is that students enroll in courses multiple times, so they get counted multiple times, which makes the numbers wrong.

Here is some sample data

```
|row | course     | student | percent_progress | percent_points |
|====|============|=========|==================|================|
| 01 | Regression | Ken     | 0.467            | 0.455          |
| 02 | Regression | Ken     | (null)           | (null)         |
| 03 | Regression | Ken     | (null)           | (null)         |
| 04 | Regression | Ryu     | 0.455            | 0.446          |
| 05 | Regression | Ryu     | 0.455            | 0.459          |
| 06 | Clustering | Ryu     | (null)           | (null)         |
| 07 | Regression | Guile   | 0.182            | 0.054          |
| 08 | Regression | Guile   | 0.182            | 0.054          |
|====|============|=========|==================|================|
```

If I were to manually go through this data, I would pick the "best" course for each person, where "best" is defined as the one with the highest values for `percent_progress` and `percent_points`. If the values are `(null)`, then it means they didn't start the course.

Here are a few of the issues I'm facing:

1. `Ken` is straightforward because he enrolled in `Regression` three times but only attempted the course once. Save `row` `01`.
2. `Ryu` is complicated because he attempted `Regression` twice and got the same `percent_progress` both times, but got more points on `row` `05`. This case throws me off because I have to compare *both* columns. Nevertheless, we want to keep `row` `05` for Ryu **and** `row` `06` because it is from a different class: `Clustering`.
3. `Guile` is a straight-up duplicate.

The output for the table above would be:

```
|row | course     | student | percent_progress | percent_points |
|====|============|=========|==================|================|
| 01 | Regression | Ken     | 0.467            | 0.455          |
| 05 | Regression | Ryu     | 0.455            | 0.459          |
| 06 | Clustering | Ryu     | (null)           | (null)         |
| 07 | Regression | Guile   | 0.182            | 0.054          |
|====|============|=========|==================|================|
```

There are a few different conditions that I need to check for and I am confused about where to even start. Someone recommended using the `rank()` function and I tried it, but I am doing something wrong because it isn't grouping by `course` and `student`, then ranking according to the two performance columns. I also don't know how it would handle cases like `Ryu's`, where he had a tie for `percent_progress` and we had to use `percent_points`. (There are other cases with the opposite pattern, so any hard-coded rule that says to just use `percent_points` won't work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (course, student) t.*
from sample t
order by course, student, percent_progress desc nulls last, percent_points desc nulls last;
```

If you prefer to use, say, the sum of the two values, you can easily adapt that:

```
order by course, student, (percent_progress + percent_points) desc nulls last
```

Comment: That just randomly selects a row and doesn't capture the conditions I specified: maximum combination of percent_progress and percent_points.

Comment: @NLR . . . It is not *random*.  It chooses the maximum percent first and then the maximum points, which seems to be what you are describing.

Comment: @Gordon--I completely missed the order by. This nailed it. Thank you very much!